# Where is 32 bit exe when target platform change

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, x86, platform

I was changed my project platform to 86 version and Build output path are change to bin\x86. But when i check Debug folder inside the bin\x86 there is nothing even after project build.Where is 32 bit exe for my project?

Comment: Well, I suppose that depends entirely on which development environment you're using, which you didn't specify.

Comment: I using Visual Studio 2008 and C#

Comment: Hit "Rebuild" instead of "Build", and see what happens.

Comment: Nothing change.I was delete whole of debug folder inside of bin and rebuild the project.There is no even debug folder.

Comment: Are you rebuilding in Debug, or in Release?

Comment: In Debug Mode.@MarkBenningfield

Comment: Okay, programmers are problem-solvers by nature, so dig in there and solve it. This is going to be something ridiculously simple. Either the build is failing and you don't realize it, or somehow the output path got changed to a different project folder, or something. As a last resort, have your .exe display it's current folder path when you run it.

Answer (score 0):

remove the contents of 'bin' folder and run again

Comment: if you are on "DEBUG" mode change it to "RELEASE" and build, now you can delete the content of debug folder and you can change "RELEASE" to "DEBUG". the application was open

Comment: this debug folder is stay empty @Saliou